# How to get mouse position over a certain control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, cursor-position

Windows Form
I'm using the DragOver event on a layoutpanel and the DragEventArgs returns the X/Y coordinates of the mouse in relation to the screen. I know there is a function to translate this in to the position of the mouse over the control, but I'm having difficulty locating it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [Control.PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) and [Control.PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx).

Comment: This answer could be improved with the code sample being put here instead of a link away.

Comment: Well you can feel free to edit it and put that code sample right in.

Comment: I haven't figured out what the code should be yet or I would :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PointToClient` method to compute the location of the specified screen point into client coordinates.

```
private void DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
        Point point = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        // then use point.X and point.Y instead of e.X and e.Y
}
```