# C# Mouse position over pictureBox

Tags: c#, mouseover, picturebox

How can I know at what pixel of a `pictureBox` the mouse is placed (coordinates)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you're looking for: a pixel information of the picture in the picture box? Or the mouse position relative to the picture box? The latter is described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465545/how-to-get-mouse-position-over-a-certain-control)

Comment: For example the mouse is pointing to a pixel of a picture box with x:10 and y:25, so I would like to know these x and y of mouse over what pixel it is located.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Catch mouse move event:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
    }
```

You have X and Y position there.
If your image has been zoomed and/or panned, rememeber you have to apply transformations on those coords.
To be clear: if your image has been placed on `(x0,y0)` and been zoomed with `zf` (remember that zf<1 means reduced), pixel coords will be

```
px = (e.X - x0) / zoom;
py = (e.Y - y0) / zoom;
```

Comment: @NewProger: I don't know if you mean this with your comment, so take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the question is a little bit vague since you did not tell us what exactly are you planning to do nor what you have effectively tried.

The [Control.PointToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method seems to do what you need:

> Computes the location of the specified screen point into client
>   coordinates.

You can then use the [Bitmap.GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) and use the X-Y coordinates to get the pixel at the given mouse co-ordinates:

> Gets the color of the specified pixel in this Bitmap

All of this can be triggered by a Mouse_Over event, Mouse_Click, etc.

Comment: Thank you npinti PointToClient solved my problem. To clarify the problem: I'm calculating: Upon which row/column was a digit-label dropped in the Soduku-grid (a PictureBox). The x/y in DragDrop's DragEventArgs are in absolute coords, I guess... whereas I need x/y relative to the picturebox.

Answer (score 2):

If you determine the color inside a MouseEvent, you can just use the coordinates provided from MouseEventArgs

```
// Declare a Bitmap
Bitmap mybitmap;
// Load Picturebox image to bitmap
mybitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

// In the mouse move event
 var pixelcolor = mybitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
// Displays R  / G / B Color
pixelcolor.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a static method on the Mouse class that allows you to get the position of the mouse pointer relative to another element . Look at [Mouse.GetPosition(UIElement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition.aspx).

Here's how you use it.

```
Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(pictureBox);

Debug.WriteLine("X: " + point.X +"\n Y: "+ point.Y);
```

Comment: Hm, but what should I add into using statement? Because for some reason "using System.Windows.Input;" gives me an error...

Comment: well, that is exactly what I did :) But no matter. I already googled it and it seems that it is not possible to use in "windowa forms application" and can only be used in W... what is it called again.. WPF or something.

Comment: oh yeah. This is part of the WPF Presentationcore library. I assumed that you wanted to do this on a WPF app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Curser.Position` in combination with the `PointToClient` method of the `PictureBox`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494690/8028981).