# How to get the mouse position and use it in the client

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a form which has a ListView. I want to show a "Picture Window" whenever mouse hovers above one of the listView Item in the ListView. I implemented this by using "ListView"'s "ItemMouseHover" event. I want to show this "Picture Window" just near to the mouse position. But , I couldn't get the mouse position from the itemmousehover event. Can anybody say how to achieve this?

Note: I am using .Net 4.0

**EDIT:** 
           "Danbystrom" gave the exact answer. But I found the root cause is some other. See my  answer for that.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465545/how-to-get-mouse-position-over-a-certain-control

Comment: @Arsen In that question he says that "DragEventArgs returns the X/Y coordinates" . In my case, I am not getting any coordinates from the event. So, this question can be considered a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static method Control.MousePosition will give you the coordinates in screen space. Then you can convert that into client coordinates with the Control.PointToClient instance method.

```
var pt = listView.PointToClient( Control.MousePosition );
```

Comment: Your answer narrowed down the problem. I found that the "picture window"'s location is changing automatically after I called show(). I am investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

The new window will be placed on your will, only if you choose "Manual" instead of "WindowsDefaultLocation" in the Property "StartPosition". Otherwise "OS" will try to put your new window's location somewhere near to the mouse position. If the new window hides the mouse in that position, then it will try through some nearby points which will result in flickering.

Comment: How does this answer "But , I couldn't get the mouse position from the itemmousehover event. Can anybody say how to achieve this?"

Comment: @danby Thank you for your comment. It prevented me from ticking the wrong answer